# How to query (retrieve) the upper (normal ranked) value from a statement in wikidata?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

[Occupation values of Steve Jobs, entrepreneur being the first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o6og.png)

Additional remark:
Usually the first submitted value in a statement is most relevant to that record and therefore that is the one that I would like to retrieve, if there is way to rank / capture only the occupation "entrepreneur" in a query where there are no preferred statements that be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is I do not think you can do this, certainly not within the SPARQL query service: the data model does not care about the order of statements, and these are purely cosmetic for display within the web interface.

While they are *generally* in order of addition, it is not guaranteed that the top one will be the one added first - if one is deleted and re-added, it will sort to the bottom, and occasionally users will do a cosmetic resort to eg place the higher ranked ones at the top, or place them in some kind of chronological order.

I had a quick look to see if the claim IDs are in any way sequential, but they don't seem to be - you can check with [this query](https://w.wiki/5VFz) if desired.

I assume the value for ordering is stored *somewhere* within wikibase, but you would probably need to process the dumps in order to retrieve it.